# Python indentation error despite correct indent

Tags: python

I am facing indentation error despite correct spaces. I am not able to figure out the exact problem

Code region :

```
def reverse(self,pos):
cur=pos
prevnode =None
nextnode=None
while cur.next!=None:
        nextnode=cur.next
        cur.next=prevnode
        prevnode=cur
        cur=nextnode
        self.head=prevnode
```

error comes at this point :

File "python", line 75
nextnode=None
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
Here's the repl link :https://repl.it/@LJ1/ConstantPurpleDisk

Comment: `while cur.next!=None:` should not be indented

Comment: The error is self-explanatory... you have an indent where there shouldn't be one on line 75.

Comment: You are using tabs and spaces to indent. Use either tab or space. Check this https://repl.it/repls/LuxuriousTestyConnections

Comment: thanks bro @serbia99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this

```
def reverse(self,pos):
    cur=pos
    prevnode=None
    nextnode=None

    while pos.next!=None:
      cur=self.head
      prevnode=None
      nextnode=None

      while cur.next!=None:
            nextnode=cur.next
            cur.next=prevnode
            prevnode=cur
            cur=nextnode
            self.head=prevnode
```